# Cannot detect any usb device in the guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am hosting a virtual Windows 7 inside a windows 10 using an Oracle Virtualbox, and the guest OS cannot detect any removable device.

besides that, I have no idea how to share files and folders between the guest and host.

anyone can help, please.

Answer (score 0):

For your USB drive, did you explicitly pass the USB drive to your guest? See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#usb-support

For other file sharing, you should use the folder sharing feature in Virtualbox: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders. You need to install guest additions for this to work. The same guide also explains how to set up a network share or drag-and-drop if either of those work better for you.